# How can I find out the current Git branch name from code, without using git itself? .git/HEAD file?

Tags: git

I am writing some jazzy code which needs to determine the current branch name programatically. I don't want to take a dependency on any git executables, I just want to look in the .git directory.

Can I just inspect the .git/HEAD file?

Comment: What's the problem with using git executables?  The git tools are specifically written to handle these sort of thing for you.  Not using the supplied tools really means reimplementing them. (personally, I do not like to reinvent to wheel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your git repository is always on a branch and has never checked out a specific SHA, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use .git/HEAD file. Mine says that rel-8.0 is the current branch:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/rel-8.0
```

If I checkout a tag it just gives me the hash:

```
$ git checkout 7.5
$ cat .git/HEAD
2a6a92d1a34af5cf229097cac63ae5b3ea0c3747
```